# How can I make terminal emulators usable on a HiRes screen?

Tags: resolution, terminal-emulator

On Debian Stretch with a 3200x1800 screen, using Cinnamon desktop, the interface size is on a nice scale.

However, I was used to work with `xterm` as a terminal. The problem: the window appears ridiculously small on my screen. Same thing with `rxvt`.

So now, I use `gnome-terminal` which works pretty well, but I don't like it *that* much.

How can I make terminal emulators usable on a high resolution screen?

Comment: Use a bigger typeface.

Comment: @Kusalananda how?

Comment: @Totor, see `man xterm`. `-fa`/`-fs` options and `faceName`/`faceSize` X11 resources. I'd expect you can configure font size in every terminal emulator. So the answer to your question would be _all_.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I changed my question from "what" to "how". If it can avoid downvoting...

Answer (score 5):

For `xterm`, load these resources into your X server (some desktop environments do that automatically from the `~/.Xresources` file upon login) so it applies to all applications of class `XTerm` connecting to it from any machine:

```
XTerm.VT100.faceName: DejaVu Sans Mono
XTerm.VT100.faceSize: 20
XTerm.SimpleMenu*font: -adobe-helvetica-bold-r-normal--24-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*
XTerm.SimpleMenu.menuLabel.font: -adobe-helvetica-bold-r-normal--34-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*
```

Adjust to taste.

Answer (score 3):

I use urxvt on a HiRes display with a large enough font configured with the following line in my `~/.Xresources` configuration file:

```
Rxvt.font: xft:DejaVuSansMono:size=7
```

There should be some equivalent configuration for most terminal emulators.

Note that after changing this file, you have to merge this file to your current resources database with `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` (or start a new X session).